# How to sample parameters without duplicates in optuna?

Tags: python, optuna

I am using optuna for parameter optimisation of my custom models.

Is there any way to sample parameters until current params set was not tested before? I mean, do try sample another params if there were some trial in the past with the same set of parameters.

In some cases it is impossible, for example, when there is categorial distribution and `n_trials` is greater than number os possible unique sampled values.

What I want: have some config param like `num_attempts` in order to sample parameters up to `num_attempts` in for-loop until there is a set that was not tested before, else - to run trial on the last sampled set.

Why I need this: just because it costs too much to run heavy models several times on the same parameters.

What I do now: just make this "for-loop" thing but it's messy.

If there is another smart way to do it - will be very grateful for information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no direct way to handle your case for now.
As a workaround, you can check for parameter duplication and skip the evaluation as follows:

```
import optuna

def objective(trial: optuna.Trial):
    # Sample parameters.
    x = trial.suggest_int('x', 0, 10)
    y = trial.suggest_categorical('y', [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10])

    # Check duplication and skip if it's detected.
    for t in trial.study.trials:
        if t.state != optuna.structs.TrialState.COMPLETE:
            continue

        if t.params == trial.params:
            return t.value  # Return the previous value without re-evaluating it.

            # # Note that if duplicate parameter sets are suggested too frequently,
            # # you can use the pruning mechanism of Optuna to mitigate the problem.
            # # By raising `TrialPruned` instead of just returning the previous value,
            # # the sampler is more likely to avoid sampling the parameters in the succeeding trials.
            #
            # raise optuna.structs.TrialPruned('Duplicate parameter set')

    # Evaluate parameters.
    return x + y

# Start study.
study = optuna.create_study()

unique_trials = 20
while unique_trials > len(set(str(t.params) for t in study.trials)):
    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks much more accurate than my custom loop. The only problem I see is that if duplicated values were sampled then current trial will be "used", there is no attempt to sample non-duplicated values (I mean, number of unique trials will be lower). That's why I don't want use pruning, because actual number of `n_trials` becomes lower than desired. But any way, if there is no such option, I will use your approach as it looks more laconic :)

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helps you. BTW, to address the problem you mentioned (i.e., "actual number of n_trials becomes lower than desired"), I updated my example code a bit. Please see the bottom three lines of the code.

Answer (score 1):

To second @sile's code comment, you may write a pruner such as:

```py
from optuna.pruners import BasePruner
from optuna.structs import TrialState
class RepeatPruner(BasePruner):
    def prune(self, study, trial):
        # type: (Study, FrozenTrial) -> bool

        trials = study.get_trials(deepcopy=False)
        
        numbers=np.array([t.number for t in trials])
        bool_params= np.array([trial.params==t.params for t in trials]).astype(bool)
        #Don´t evaluate function if another with same params has been/is being evaluated before this one
        if np.sum(bool_params)>1:
            if trial.number>np.min(numbers[bool_params]):
                return True

        return False
```

then call the pruner as:

```py
study = optuna.create_study(study_name=study_name, storage=storage, load_if_exists=True, pruner=RepeatPruner())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One question - is it right that if I do `n_trials = 5`, among them there are 2 param sets that are the same (so therefore 4 unique sets were sampled), then using pruner I will have only 4 tried attempts/trials, right? 

I mean pruner drops duplicated sample, doesn't try to resample another params.

Comment: You may still use @sile’s `while` loop to force the optimizer try the exact number of trials as you want. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: just as a note, pruners are not supported for multi-objective optimization